# React ScrollIntoView Does not work when scrolled to top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollview

The Problem :- The scrollIntoView is working fine but, it fails for this scenario when suppose I click on `John Doe` it scrolls to that section but now when I scroll to top and select again `John Doe` then it does not get scrolled to that particular section Why is this happening ?
**Note :-** This happens for all the buttons not just for `John Doe`

In the `useEffect` Dependency array I have added the `selectedAdvisor` state variable so that whenever it changes then it should scrollIntoView of that section based on the `id`

Expected Output :- scrollIntoView should work properly even if I scroll to top and then select the element that was already selected example `John Doe`

Below is my code :-

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function AdvisorCard() {
  return <div className="advisorCard"></div>;
}
export const NewFilterAdvisor = () => {
  const [selectedAdvisor, setSelectedAdvisor] = useState("Tony Stark");

  useEffect(() => {
    let ele = document.getElementById(`${selectedAdvisor}`);
    if (ele) {
      ele.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
      });
    }
  }, [selectedAdvisor]);

  return (
    <div className="newFilterAdvisorContainer">
      <div className="advisorsBtnContainer">
        <button
          onClick={() => setSelectedAdvisor("Tony Stark")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Tony Stark
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSelectedAdvisor("Steve Rogers")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Steve Rogers
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSelectedAdvisor("Bruce Banner")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Bruce Banner
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSelectedAdvisor("Thor")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Thor
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSelectedAdvisor("John Doe")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          John Doe
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="Tony Stark" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Tony's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Steve Rogers" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Steve's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Bruce Banner" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Bruce's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Thor" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Thor's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="John Doe" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">John's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CodeSandBoxLink :- https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-darkness-g42qjw?file=/src/App.js:1443-1470

Where am I going wrong ? please help

Comment: Because the state remains same so useEffect won't called again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is that if you select same item after you scroll up, you'd update the state to the same value and the `useEffect` won't run. Actually you don't even need an internal state. This would do just fine:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function AdvisorCard() {
  return <div className="advisorCard"></div>;
}
export default function App() {
  const handleSelectItem = (id) => {
    let ele = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
    if (ele) {
      ele.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center"
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="newFilterAdvisorContainer">
      <div className="advisorsBtnContainer">
        <button
          onClick={() => handleSelectItem("Tony Stark")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Tony Stark
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => handleSelectItem("Steve Rogers")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Steve Rogers
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => handleSelectItem("Bruce Banner")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Bruce Banner
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => handleSelectItem("Thor")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          Thor
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => handleSelectItem("John Doe")}
          className="advisorBtn"
        >
          John Doe
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="Tony Stark" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Tony's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Steve Rogers" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Steve's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Bruce Banner" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Bruce's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Thor" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">Thor's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="John Doe" className="advisorSection">
        <h1 className="advisorCardContainerHeading">John's Advisors</h1>
        <div className="advisorCardContainer">
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
          <AdvisorCard />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```